# IntelliJ: Disable "TS80006: This may be converted to an async function."

Tags: eslint, webstorm, intellij-14

In WebStorm, How can I disable the warning (aka. "quick-fix"):

```
TS80006: This may be converted to an async function.
```

*By 'warning' I mean the function name is underlined, and I see the warning text on hover:*

[image: Screenshot of the warning, incl. options]

I would expect the setting for this warning to be under `Settings / Editor / Inspections` somewhere, but I can't find it when I search for "async function" or "quick fix" or "inspections".

*(I assume this setting is the same or similar in WebStorm and IntelliJ)*

E.g. this warning is displayed for a function like:

```
const f = (): Promise<string[]> => {
  return util()
    .then( mapFunction1 )
    .then( mapFunction2 );
};
```

WebStorm suggest to change it to:

```
const f = async (): Promise<string[]> => {
  const s = await util();
  const s_1 = await mapFunction1( s );
  return mapFunction2( s_1 );
};
```

But I still prefer the `.then()` variant, as it is better readable for me.

#### EDIT:

I found the "Editor / Intentions" section after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76818795/7556457), but after disabling "Convert to async function" the warning still appears:

[image: Screenshot of my "Intentions" setting]

Interestingly, after that, "Convert to async function" it is not suggested anymore in the "more actions" menu, but the "suggestion" is still displayed in the code (including the hover box):

[image: Screenshot of the warning after disabling "Convert to async function"]

Comment: *"`TS80006:`"* -- this suggests that it is coming from TS itself and not the IDE's own functionality. Please invoke "More Actions" from your screenshot and show what the menu will show (alternatively place the caret on the error/suggestion place in the editor and invoke the Quick Fix/Intentions menu via `Alt+Enter` (or using a mouse: click on the light bulb icon)).

Comment: That makes totally sense... but on the other hand, `// @ts-ignore` doesn't disable this warning. _(i'll add the "more actions" box in the screenshot)_

Comment: *"// `@ts-ignore` doesn't disable this warning."* From what I see it's not a Warning but a Suggestion only (although it may use similar styling). Hard to say here without seeing the whole thing myself.

Comment: Anyway: Expand the submenu for that "Convert to async function" entry (just `Arrow Right` on your keyboard, much easier than using a mouse) -- there will be quite a few option. You should be able to disable this Inspection/Intention from there (or maybe better for the moment: just suppress it for the statement (via additional IDE-generated special comment). **I suggest** you first check what inspection/intention that is (choose the appropriate action and it will open the right settings entry for you -- if not sure which one -- post another screenshot with the submenu content)

Comment: Interesting ... I disabled that warning in the "more actions" menu (that menu item lead me directly to the same "intentions -> Javascript -> ECMAScript 6 -> Convert to async function" setting mentioned in [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76818795/7556457), which I already had tried). After that, "Convert to async function" it is not suggested anymore in the "more actions" menu, but the "suggestion" is still displayed in the code. -- I've updated my screenshots to include the new information.

Comment: Your last screenshot now shows "Unused constant myFunction" which is obviously different inspection. The "Convert to async function" in More Actions -- well, it's an intention so it can be there (although it's unexpected to see it there after disabling it in the Intentions, but then: I'm not really JS/TS person + it has "TS" icon so may work differently i.e. done by the TS service itself and not the IDE).

Comment: If `myFunction` is actually used later in the file and the Unused const warning is wrong ... I may suggest trying `File | Invalidate Caches...`, restart the IDE and let it reindex the project -- maybe some caching...

Comment: Ah, crap, sorry. I must have removed the console.log where I used `myFunction`. I updated the screenshot. -- Unfortunately I can't create a screenshot with all boxes open at the same time, so i have to stitch them together.

Comment: That's as much as I may help you right now. I may only suggest to try the aforementioned Invalidate Caches (will not hurt) and try with all custom (not bundled by default) plugins disabled to see if it will make things any different. Other than that: no ideas (and since I'm not JS/TS person I do not think I can make the same setup as yours to test it all locally).

Comment: Fair enough. I have not custom plugins installed. I also tried disabling the `TSLint` plugin, and disabling `Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript -> TSLint`, then 'invalidate and restart' and 'restart Typscript service'. Still no change.

Comment: This happens in a new project created with: `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`

Comment: I suggest you use `Help | Contact Support...` that will take you to the JetBrains website were you can make a private Support Ticket and provide all relevant info. The same URL to submit the ticket ("Submit a Request" big blue button on the WebStorm Forums site) : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: This is a TS issue not Webstorm - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61326

Comment: There also is a Webstorm issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62609/Impossible-to-disable-TS80006-TS80006-This-may-be-converted-to-an-async-function. -- it says "We have a feature request for a possibility to not highlight them in editor, WEB-62507. The fix will be available in 2023.2.2"

Answer (score 5):

I found a setting that toggles this warning on and off:

`Settings` / `Languages & Frameworks` / `TypeScript` / `TypeScript language service` / `Show suggestions`.

This warning apparently comes from the ["TypeScript Language Service"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-languages-typescript.html).

The `Show suggestions` option seems to be [new in version 2023.2.2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62507/Opportunity-to-turn-off-optional-TypeScript-service-inspections#focus=Comments-27-7991095.0-0), according to the probably related issue [WEB-62507](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-62507/Opportunity-to-turn-off-optional-TypeScript-service-inspections).

Apparently there isn't a more detailed configuration (e.g. to just disable this one "suggestion", instead of "Show suggestions" in general).

Answer (score 2):

1. Open WebStorm and go to `Settings`
2. In the settings dialog, navigate to `Editor`
3. In the search bar at the top of the settings dialog, type `This may be converted to an async function`
4. This rule should be present in `Intentions` tab.

[image]

Comment: Hm. Thank you. But I don't have the "JavaScript" section, I only have "Javascript and Typescript. Are you using IntelliJ, or Webstorm, or something else ? _(Maybe my assumption that it should be the same was wrong.)_

Comment: WebStorm as well, `Build #WS-231.9161.29, built on June 15, 2023`

Comment: Do you see any similar option in Intentions tab?

Comment: Which language version was set up in Settings -> Language and Frameworks -> JavaScript ?

Comment: OH, it's "Intentions", I always read "Inspections" (which made sense for me) ! I never even recognized that category. I have found that setting then. But the warning still appears if I disable it. :/ (I'll also research what "Intentions" is supposed to do.)

Comment: @kca can you make screenshot how is it shown to you? Because I don't have any warning after disabling (only I see the line on hovering variable).

If bulb is annoying, it can be disabled in settings

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/intention-actions.html#disable-intention

Comment: I've added screenshots. These "Intentions" look like the _kind_ of setting what I'm looking for, but I don't see that bulb at all, but only an underline under the function name. -- To answer your earlier question: Settings -> Language and Frameworks -> JavaScript -> JavaScript language version: "ECMAScript 6+"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254762/discussion-between-yaroslavm-and-kca).

Comment: I disabled that setting but the warning is still displayed. That's because it comes from TypeScript, not from Webstorm (the "TS" error code always is) -- see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61326